# why do we need static methods in class of javascript

Tags: javascript, class, oop, ecmascript-6

why do we need static methods in class of javascript.

```
class Car {
  constructor(brand) {
    this.carname = brand;
  }
  static hello(x) {
    return "Hello " + x.carname;
  }
}

mycar = new Car("Ford");

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Car.hello(mycar);
```

I know that , Static methods are called directly on the class (Car from the example above) - without creating an instance/object (mycar) of the class.
But what's the use of/point of static method in classes JS.

Answer (score 11):

**To be able to call the method without creating an instance of the class.**

There's some benefit to this.  To call an instance method, you would have to create a new instance of the class, and then call the method (it's a two-step process).  With `static` methods, this isn't necessary.

More info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static):

> Static methods are often utility functions, such as functions to create or clone objects, whereas static properties are useful for caches, fixed-configuration, or any other data you don't need to be replicated across instances.

Static functions are typically *referentially-transparent functions.*  A referentially-transparent function is one that doesn't rely on *instance* state for its proper functioning.  Such a function is easy to reason about, because you don't have to consider anything that is happening *outside* of the function to understand what it does.

Comment: A specific example of creating objects that is impossible to achieve with the constructor alone since `async constructor` is illegal, is to define static asynchronous factory functions, which delegate to the constructor after awaiting asynchronously provided dependencies that are parameters of the constructor.

Comment: Please consider that this is a duplicate question.

Comment: It's a duplicate question, but this is the clearest answer.

Answer (score 0):

Static methods give the method to the constructor of the class... not the instance. This makes it so you can call ClassName.functionName(param); Instances will still have this function, but it makes it so you can call the function on the class instead of the instance.
For example, this doesn't work:

```js
class jump
  doJump() {
    console.log(7);
  }
}
jump.doJump(); // Error
var jumper = new jump();
jumper.jump() // => 7
```

But this does:

```js
class move {
  static doMove() {
    console.log("works");
  }
}
move.doMove();
var t = new Move()
t.doMove();
```

Comment: these examples don't really demonstrate the utility of static class methods, since both of these could just as easily be achieved with the easier-to-understand object literals `const jump = { doJump() { ... } };` and `const move = { doMove() { ... } };` respectively. Also, `t.doMove();` would not work.